# Create a "dismissable" buffer

Tags: buffers

I am writing a simple package for myself to try and learn some elisp - and to begin extending Emacs for my own personal workflow. This function processes the current buffer contents with a command line utility and pipes the output into a temporary buffer. This is what I have so far, and it processes the buffer as desired

```
(defun doStuff ()
  (interactive)
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*stuffed*"
    (shell-command
     (..cli stuff here...)
     (pop-to-buffer "*stuffed*")
     ))
  )
```

What I'm looking for is a way to replace the contents of the *current* buffer, in such a way that if I press "q" it will revert to the original buffer contents. Can anyone give me some pointers on how I might go about that?

Comment: Rather than revert the contents of a non-file-visiting-buffer (e.g. one big undo), it would probably be better to create a different buffer to hold the new information.  Programmatically, "q" would be choosing one version over the other.  You may also wish to look at cloning the original buffer if you need the data it contains.

Comment: Along the lines of what @lawlist said, you can set the mode of your *\*stuffed\** buffer to `(special-mode)`. Then when you hit `q` in that buffer, that buffer window will quit *without killing the buffer* (default binding in `special-mode-map`). Hitting `C-u q` will quit that window *and* kill that buffer.

Comment: @kaushalmodi is (special-mode) a built in mode? would either of you care to elaborate on your comments to in the form of an answer?

Comment: A note: please follow Emacs Lisp naming conventions, so `doStuff` should be `do-stuff` or rather `my-package-do-stuff`. This will save you time fixing it later if you want to put it into some package archive after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a variation of your implementation:

```el
(defun my-do-stuff ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((cmd "your cmd here")
        (temp-buf-name "*stuffed*"))
    ;; Create a buffer `temp-buf-name' and run the shell command in it
    (get-buffer-create temp-buf-name)
    (let ((message-log-max nil)) ; Don't clutter *Messages* buffer (optional)
      (shell-command cmd temp-buf-name))
    ;; Switch to the `temp-buf-name' buffer
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window temp-buf-name)
    ;; Set its major mode to `special-mode'
    (special-mode) ; a read-only major mode
    ;; As you are now in the `temp-buf-name' buffer, you can do the below:
    ;; - hit `q' to quit the current window *without* killing `temp-buf-name'
    ;; - hit `C-u q' to quit the current window *and* kill `temp-buf-name'
    ))
```

---

The `special-mode-map` default bindings are defined in `simple.el`:

```el
(defvar special-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (suppress-keymap map)
    (define-key map "q" 'quit-window)
    (define-key map " " 'scroll-up-command)
    (define-key map [?\S-\ ] 'scroll-down-command)
    (define-key map "\C-?" 'scroll-down-command)
    (define-key map "?" 'describe-mode)
    (define-key map "h" 'describe-mode)
    (define-key map ">" 'end-of-buffer)
    (define-key map "<" 'beginning-of-buffer)
    (define-key map "g" 'revert-buffer)
    map))
```

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. i'm trying to figure out how to apply syntax highlighting to the output - i'm transpiling some JS - i guess i'd need to make a minor mode to handle it instead of special?

Comment: If the syntax highlighting is for some known language, then you can enable that language's major mode, make the buffer read-only and then bind `q` as you want *only* in that buffer.